# Input range - on value increase (value++) vs on value decrease (value--)

Tags: javascript, jquery, range

I am testing a script that includes a range slider and I ran into a problem while trying to return a different output depending on the range value, here is what I mean by this...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#controller').on('input', function(){
    let value = $('#volume').val();
    if(value++){
        console.log('Value Increased');
    }
    else if(value--){
        console.log('Value Decreased');
    }
});
});
```

Now, what happens is that no matter if you increase or decrease the value of the slider it always returns "Value Increased" except in case when you put the slider on 0 in which case it returns "Value Decreased"...

This is my first time working with range sliders, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think `console.log(value)` could give you right key

Comment: The condition in your `if` does not do what you expect. Read up a bit on JavaScript operators and revisit your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `value++` and `value--` will always return an integer, not a boolean value. Using a non-zero integer in an `if` condition will always coerce to `true`, hence you always see 'Value increased' unless the value is `0`.

To do what you require the correct logic would be to store the previous slider value and compare it to the latest one, like this:

```js
let oldValue = $('#controller').val(); // set when the DOM loads

$('#controller').on('input', function() {
  let currentValue = $('#controller').val();
  if (currentValue > oldValue) {
    console.log('Value Increased');
  } else if (currentValue < oldValue) {
    console.log('Value Decreased');
  } else {
    console.log('No change');
  }
  oldValue = currentValue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="controller" min="0" max="100" />
```